Webcam on dell XPS 13 not working
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 on a dell XPS 13 9315 and suddenly started having issues with my webcam.
The camera does not seem to turn on and just shows black in each application I try (chrome, cheese, kamoso, zoom). Previously, when the camera was wokring, the light next to it would come on. Now the light never comes on.
v4l2-ctl recognized Intel MIPI Camera as well as some ipu6 devices:
sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
[sudo] password for benc: 
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video8

ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/media0

Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

The output of lsusb does not seem to recognize the camera:
sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:63ac Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Following other answers, I made sure that libcamhal-ipu6ep0 is installed properly. This did not seem to make any difference.

This camera is big problem not having full support yet, according to dell should be working on Ubuntu 22.04, but did not work on newer versions like Ubuntu 24.
In your case can be related a some update, like in the kernel version, so stop working for you. Maybe a option is to boot with a older version of the kernel to see if fix the problem.
To add more context this Dell article your dell XPS 13 9315 is listed as have the problem on 24 version. So I think for you is just related to some update happen to fix this problem.

Affected Product
Latitude 7340, Latitude 7440, Latitude 9430, Latitude 7640, Precision 5480, > Precision 5490, Precision 5680, Mobile Precision 5690, XPS 13 9315

You can try take a look on sudo dmesg -T output. For example the error appearing for me.
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230925
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Found supported sensor INT3474:01
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Connected 1 cameras
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
ov2740 i2c-INT3474:01: error -EREMOTEIO: failed to find sensor

You can also take a look on this issue thread on GithHub to try some commands
